# Problem with wordpress has_action() function

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, javascript

Inside a WordPress plugin i am trying to check whether shutdown hook exists or not using `has_action()` function.I am trying to alert a message based on the checking.The problem is when the `has_action()` function is not executed due to cache then the code does not show any alert message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=<?php echo has_action('shutdown');?>; 

if (typeof flag !== 'undefined' || flag !== false || flag === 1) {
 alert('shutdown hook exists');
}
else {
alert('no shutdown hooks');
}
</script>
```

Comment: `has_action` will return a boolean or an integer. It will never return `undefined`, so your second alert will never fire.

Comment: what will happen if has_action is never executed due to cache ? That's why i was checking undefined !

Comment: You might want  to file an [edit] and explain how you cache and why you can not turn off cache.

Comment: It's not possiblet o answer this question  without seeing the code in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357780/errors-while-using-ajax-from-external-wordpress-page which would reveal why this won't work

Comment: @query it's unclear why  you would do this or what you're trying to achieve, you'll need to add a lot more context to this question or it won't make sense to anybody trying to answer it. Focus on your original problem rather than trying to fix your technical solution when asking

Comment: Its working now in my coding i was missing "typeof"  while comparing the variable .that's why  it was not working when the value was undefined!