# Errors while using ajax from external wordpress page

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, ajax

I am trying fetch  WordPress user data from an external page within same domain using ajax.The problem is i am getting errors which contain the user data and source code from one of my plugin.

here is my code

**external_page.php**

```
<?php
    require './wp-load.php';

    $type=isset($_POST["type"]);

        if ($type=="showlist")
        {   //here data is fetched from wordpress database
             foreach ( $users as $info ) 
           {

             $response = [$info->user_login => $info->user_email];

            }
             echo json_encode($response);        
            exit;
         }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<button id="recover" name="recover" class="btn btn-info" onclick="loadadmin()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> recover account</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadadmin() {

        $.ajax({
        url:'external_page.php',
        method:'POST', 

        data:{
         type:'showlist'         },
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response) {
         alert('success');
       },
       error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error msg :"+ xhr.responseText);
       }

      });



}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the code of my plugin

**sample_plugin.php**

```
<?php
/**
  Plugin headers
 **/
    function global_session_value()
 {
    echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">

    sessionStorage.setItem(\"lastname\", \"Smith\");

    </script>";


    }


    add_action( 'shutdown', 'global_session_value');

?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var global_value=<?php echo has_action('shutdown');?>;

</script>
```

I am getting following ajax error response message from my external page

```
    error msg:
   //code from sample_plugin.php 
   <script type="text/javascript" >
    var global_value=1;

    </script>

    {"user1":"demo@mysite.com"}//this the ajax response

   //code from sample_plugin.php   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    </script>
```

I get success alert when i disable the plugin `"sample_plugin"`. How to solve this problem so that i can get the success response without disabling the plugin?

Comment: I'm unsure what your plugin is as plugins have a header comment and don't output directly yet yours does, it's also not clear what your page and the AJAX is trying to do. In WordPress you don't have standalone PHP files that serve requests, everything gets routed through WordPress. If your goal is to list users on a page, you could do that with a page template, a JS file, and a REST API endpoint in 1/3rd of the code

Comment: The goal of the plugin is to set two global variables based on a condition so that i can access it later inside my plugin.My page is a standalone PHP file from where i am trying to list user names from wordpress database using wordpress environment.Any idea why the ajax is returning those  javascript from the plugin ?

Comment: **That's not how PHP works, you can't set variables in 1 request, then read them in another**. Every page request loads WP from scratch,  once it's served the page it's all wiped. There is no persistent application running in the background like Java or Node applications, each request spawns a new process. Even if it was ( which it isn't ), you shouldn't be using standalone PHP files to do it, use the REST API, or even the old admin AJAX interface. If you want information to carry over across different requests, you have to store it somewhere persistent

Comment: where you have found that i am trying to set and get variables from different request ?? May be you are assuming "sample_plugin.php" as an standalone php page! But it is a sample plugin and i am not looking persistent solution and happy with the new value generated by wp each time.I know that i am not using ajax in wp way but it still works if i disable the plugin.when the plugin is enabled ajax response outputs my inline script so i think i am doing something wrong with inline scripting.